# PHP redirection with post values

Tags: php, redirect

Is it possible to redirect user to external server without using:
`header('Location:address.com?var=1');`
or
HTML form with JS auto submit

Seems really simple but can't figure it out. I do not want to use GET, I would rather send it via headers/post if possible. 
Making ajax request is slowing it down and I believe there should be some kind of solution in pure PHP.

CURL is not an option as I want to go to that link with posted data.

Cheers

Comment: Put the external URL in the `action` of your form.

Comment: Take a look here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: @MaggsWeb This actually does not help as I do not want to use HTML form at all.

Comment: you're contradicting yourself. To answer, you can use a meta refresh tag

Comment: @Fred-ii- No I can't use meta refresh tag. As you can't send variable in other way than in the link with this kind of tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this method session_set_cookie_params(). It is used to transfer data from 1 url to another url using session. To get the result you have to write this function before every session_start().

```
session_set_cookie_param();
@session_start();
```